# Type A cannot be converted to type B in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, casting, runtime-error

Getting this error ever once in a while in a ASP.NET forms page during a partial postback.

> [A]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.Int32,ArgoWeb.CommissionsMgmt+Alteration] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.Int32,ArgoWeb.CommissionsMgmt+Alteration]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

Note that both types are identical and they both originate from the same place.

Comment: Different `ArgoWeb.CommissionsMgmt+Alteration` assemblies, possibly? I suspect that the error message wasn't designed for cases when the type arguments are from the wrong assemblies...

Comment: I narrowed down the problem. The error only occurs if I make a change to the page and then do a post back on that page from the same page that was loaded before the change. The casting occurs when my custom control state is reconstituted. So I think what's happening is behind the scenes the compiler compiles the page again and creating a new assembly. Still don't get why that should error out though. It is the same exact generic Dictionary type. My page change is not changing the type.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that there's some serialized data which includes a temporary filename which was the originally-compiled assembly... and then can't be deserialized with the later location.